# Magento What is the Best Way to Resolve Observer Load Order Issue?

Tags: magento, observers, load-order

I need to insert a javascript object into the head of my listing pages containing a json representation of the products listed on that page, i.e. not all products in the category but only those that have been paged by the toolbar.

I've found that I can get that data by putting an observer on catalog_block_product_list_collection but this is after the Head Block has been rendered, so therefore prevents me using that data in a child block of the Head.

As far as I can see I've got two options.

1. Load a javascript block to the footer and use jquery to inject it to the header.
2. Work out what Magento did before catalog_block_product_list_collection was called and recreate the logic in my model.

I wondered which way experienced Magento developers would jump and the pitfalls of both techniques, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you already have added a custom block to the header, if I got you right, if so, you should be able to just retrieve the product collection from the list block.

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list')->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

I might have misunderstood your question, but maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks @butterbrot this looks like it might do the job, I wasn't aware you could get the parent layout from the block itself, though it seems obvious now really when I think about it. I'll give it a go. I'll come back and let you know the outcome.

Comment: it pulls in a product collection but the paging hasn't been applied neither in my object or in the product_list block itself displaying all on the page. I think that calling getLoadedProductCollection() loads product collection if null and as a singleton. Mage must normally have been doing some setup work that we've side stepped and therefore prevented, I could solve the singleton issue by cloning the object and the products would display correctly on the page, however in my head json I'd still have two many products. Looks like I need to clone AND work out what the setup work is.

Comment: RE: my above comment and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980721/magento-get-results-view-html-for-a-collection-of-products) I think I'm back to my initial question, is it better to recreate the logic as in the linked answer, or use the observer and use jquery to inject the json into the header? Interested in your or others views.

Comment: @FlorinelChis your answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980721/magento-get-results-view-html-for-a-collection-of-products) question seems relevant my question above, so I wondered if you had any thoughts?

Comment: I've just realised that I didn't put your username @butterbrot in my replies to your comments. Apologies if you've already received them... but I'm unsure if you get them automatically or not, the instructions say the post author will always be notified, but being a new user I'm confused as to whether I'm the post owner of the whole question, or you're the post owner of the answer you gave?? :-~

Comment: Hey, hmmm, the pager get's setup in the _beforeToHtml() so my trick will not work for you :( sry. I am not sure if I have a quick solution for you on this one. However maybe we can solve your problem by looking at it differently; Why does the JSON code need to be defined in the header?

Comment: It needs to be defined in the header because its for use by the [QuBit Tag Management system](http://www.qubitproducts.com/tag-management) the third party javascripts script tags can be injected dynamically either to the head or the foot, if they are loaded to the head they won't have access to the json if it's loaded in the foot. So I could use Jquery to inject it to the header, or I could recreate the paging logic. so @butterbrot I'm thinking that jQuery injection is probably best as recreating the logic seems a bit error prone to me.

Comment: Well, I am not sure about that QuBit tag thingy, but injecting source with jQuery to the top will not make code to be available from the "beginning" of load. I doubt that it will work. Is that code supposed to be in the header so that some code afterwards can access it. Do you have control over what is accessing it? Means can you add it to the end of your page and make sure that what ever code that requires that data is included afterwards?

Comment: 1.) yes the code is supposed be in the header so later loading code can access it.
2.) I can't control which codes will need to load in head as they are third party
3.) Whilst I take your point about the injection i'm pretty sure it will work because the scripts themselves are injected so as long as I inject before QuBit injects it should work - none of the scripts that call the object will be hard coded in the page.
Thanks @butterbrot

Comment: so @butterbrot Probably at this point I need to suck it and see - :D

Comment: @WayneTheisinger if all the other scripts are injected at well, then don't inject any just place everything to the bottom. As long as the order is the same its good.

Comment: thanks @butterbrot - if you want to do a two line summary of the ending recommendation, I'll mark it as the answer so that you get the reputation points.